# How can I upload folders from my mac to Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one, mac, directory

I use Ubuntu One to move files and documents from my Mac to my Acer and/or iphone. I can easily move individual files but I have a folder with about 200 files that I want to upload. Can this be done?

Comment: When you say 'I have a folder with about 200 files that I want to upload', you are talking about from the Mac right? Welcome to the site and I hope we can answer your question as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

We don't currently have a MacOS X client for Ubuntu One, so the web site is the primary supported mechanism for that platform.

With that in mind, if you are willing to try out some less well polished software you might want to try out a small program I've been working on as a demonstration of the Ubuntu One APIs.

You can download it from:

http://people.canonical.com/~jamesh/u1ftp.zip

Once you've downloaded it, open a terminal and run `python u1ftp.zip`.  This will start up a small FTP server listening for connections on `localhost`, port `2121`.  If you connect with an FTP client using your Ubuntu One credentials, it should give you access to your cloud storage.  Assuming the FTP client has a way to upload an entire folder, this may be a bit easier than using the web site.

You will probably need a third party FTP client though: while Finder can browse FTP sites, it apparently doesn't support uploads via FTP.

Answer (score 0):

Today you can use ubuntu one for mac https://one.ubuntu.com/downloads/mac/

"Simply select which folders you want to sync to your personal cloud by adding them to the sync list. Ubuntu One will take care of the rest."